# Script tags in body do not get evaluated after previous JavaScript errors

Tags: java, javascript, htmlunit

I have one HTML file where a JavaScript method (say) `postIt()` is defined inside the `<script>` tag. Its tag is preceded by two references to external JavaScript files which no longer exist. All these `<script>` tags are inside `<body>`.

I had to set `WebClient.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode` to false, so that I can proceed with the non-existent JavaScript files.

But when I try calling `page.executeJavascript("postIt()")`,  I get *Reference not found* error!

1. What is the reason for this and do we have any possible workaround?
2. Does the JavaScript engine run in its own thread?

Answer (score 6):

Most JavaScript engines stop parsing/evaluating code when they encounter parsetime/compiletime errors, just like other compilers.

This is a feature, not a bug.

The workaround is to fix the errors.

Comment: When an error is encountered then that particular JS is no longer parsed but that doesn't effect parsing of other scripts. Here two preceding JS were not found, so this should not skip the next script tag.

Comment: Well it seems FF and IE does process them. Shouldn't HtmlUnit behave as such?

Comment: @AppleGrew: I don't have any knowledge about HtmlUnit, but i can read on the frontpage of http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/ that "It has fairly good JavaScript support" - my guess is that their javascript implementation doesn't quite match that of the browsers.

Comment: Hmm maybe. I have now removed the offending js files. Now still it cannot find the postIt() JS function defined in the Html. :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it turns out, I was invoking incorrect JavaScript code which in turn redirected my code to a 404 page. But since I had set `webClient.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode()` and `webClient.setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode()` to false, HtmlUnit didn't notify me about this.

So for these kind of issues we need to keep the above flags turned on, and remove ALL JavaScript errors.